# Getting date from DateFormatter without delimiter(/ or -) returns wrong date:

Tags: ios, swift, date-formatting

Getting date from DateFormatter without delimiter returns the wrong date,

As per our requirement, we cannot use / or - in our date formatter string.

```
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
  dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
  dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
  dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)

  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "ddMMyyyy"
  dateFormatter.date(from: "1112987")
```

this returns "Nov 1, 2987 at 8:00 AM", however it should be "Dec 11 0987"

Another Example:

```
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMddyyyy"
  dateFormatter.date(from: "1131987") // "Jan 13, 1987 at 12:00 AM"
```

This should return nil as November 31st is a invalid date

Please suggest any solution

Comment: Do you only handle 3 digit years?

Comment: `dateFormatter.date(from: "1112987")` will return a Date object not a String representation.

Comment: What is the point to represent dates as a string if the result is confusing and possibly ambigious? The requirement is wrong.

Comment: You say 2 digits for month, 2 for day, and four for year, but you then provide a seven digit string. Why would you expect it to disregard the required number of digits for year, but not for month or day?

Comment: "yyyy" with four "y", needs 4 digits (leading zero if needed). Cf: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns You can use "yyy" (three "y"), but then you can't might have issue with year with four digits in the string.

Comment: @SulthanI need to check if the inputted data is a valid date or not, I believe this converting string to date is the only option to do it, Please suggest any other solution if you believe the requirement is wrong.

Comment: In a comment of a deleted question, you said: "I also cannot change yyyy to yyy as the date is being inputted in a text field by the user and it's being checked whenever text changes", so I think the issue lies there. You need to validate the date by the textfield (plenty of questions about that in SO), or use a DatePicker.

Comment: @Larme Changing "yyyy" to "yyy" is not possible as this information is coming from a server based on country

Comment: The server shouldn't be based on country. That's a bad design. It should convert whatever is the entry into a standard date: String representation using some ISO, like the 8601, using unix timestamp, etc.

Comment: @all please understand the actual issue before downvoting the question. I might go ahead and make it work using some string manupulation by adding 0 before year or changeing yyyy to yyy, 
but the question here is about the DateFormatter in iOS sdk, Am I using it incorectly or is it bevahing incorrectly as other platforms can parse it correctly

Comment: I didn't downvote. It seems to be a valid use of DateFormatter. Its behavior doesn't surprise me. You still can do it manually: `var dateString = "1131987"; if dateString.count < 8 { let sub1 = String(dateString.prefix(4)); var sub2 = String(dateString.suffix(dateString.count - 4)) while sub2.count < 4 { sub2 = "0" + sub2 } dateString = sub1 + sub2 }}`? But what if the input is using 1 instead of 01 for January or the first day of the month? Is it a possible input?

Comment: Your input strings are ambiguous and to declare “Dec 11, 987” as any more “correct” than “Nov 1, 2987” (or “Jan 11, 2987”, for that matter) is specious. If you have some in-house rules about how strings less than 8 digits should be parsed, then you’ll simply have write code to deal with these edge cases. Sorry. It’s not a matter that `DateFormatter` is handling it incorrectly or that you’re using `DateFormatter` incorrectly, but rather that this in-house coding convention is simply a poor design choice. There are reasons why there are well established conventions for this stuff.

Comment: @Larme The problem here is the format is derived from the server, I don't know at runtime it will be MMddyyyy or yyyyddMM or ddMMyyyy or ddyyyyMM

Comment: Wait a moment. you can't know if "11012000" is "1st of November 2000" or "11th of January 2000"? That's bad design, really bad design. It doesn't matter here if there is "-" or "/" separator, it's just bad design.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your date format from `ddMMyyyy` to `MMddyyyy`.

**Your code :-**
`dateFormatter.dateFormat = "ddMMyyyy"`

**New code :-**
`dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMddyyyy"`

Also, you have to set 4 digit year instead of 3 digit.

**Your code :-**
`dateFormatter.date(from: "1112987")`

**New code :-**
`dateFormatter.date(from: "11120987"`

If you get any issue post your reply.

Comment: As date format is coming from the server, I cannot go ahead and inset 0 at the beginning of only year characters. I'll have to deal with lots of string manipulation as format and string both are dynamic based on user locale and preference.

Comment: Then you have to update your API response. Because end of task any one have to manage either iOS developer or API developer.